# Swift: How remove Cashed Responses from URLCache by date

Tags: swift, urlcache

### What I'm try to do?

[Remove existing responses in URLCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcache/1415231-removecachedresponses) prior a given date.

### How I try to do that?

removeCachedResponses(since: date)

```swift
 func resetCache(_ since: Date) {
        self.cache.removeCachedResponses(since: since)
    }
```

Cashed responses where stored with:

```swift
...
let cachedData = CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: data)
self.cache.storeCachedResponse(cachedData, for: request)
...
```

Deleting cached responses works with

```swift
self.cache.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

EDIT: Only when you wait a bit. Imho the removing is done async.
For that reason not every image is deleted immediately from cache.
So I decided to add a small wait before start loading fresh one.

```swift
func reloadImages() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            self.loadImages(for: self.dataModel.loadDemoData(count: 5))
        }
        
    }
```

and

```swift
self.cache.removeCachedResponse(for: request)
```

But the cashed request aren't removed
Do I have to use specify a specific date format or do I have to save a date value during storing the cache?

Comment: You are not using passing argument. You just deleting data that has been created 1min ago till now. Instead of `cache.removeCachedResponses(since: resetDate)` try `cache.removeCachedResponses(since: since)`

Comment: @matsotaa omg i totally misunderstood this:
"The earliest date of responses that should remain in the cache. Any responses with dates later than this parameter should be removed."

Comment: @matsotaa I changed the code so it deletes with day - 1, that works sometime and sometime not.

Comment: I can assume first time worked, but second not? If so I can assume it correct properly since after the first time the are nothing to delete? If I missed something I need more info, cause for me it seems it should work as expected